# Swift: iphone simulator pinch gesture not working?

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, uipinchgesturerecognizer

So I dragged a pinch gesture recognizer into my storyboard and hooked that up to an IBAction to feed an image into an ImageView when the user does the pinch motion. However when I run the simulator and do the pinch motion with the option key and everything, nothing happens/ is recognized. What's going on?

My code:

```
@IBAction func pinchGesture(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        eggView.image = UIImage (named: "Easter_egg")
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that everything is well connected in storyboard? There is a ball on left side of the @IBAction. Is it full or empty?

Comment: It's full. Everything is connected

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. It seems to be gesture recognizer don't properly added to the view and the solution is to add gesture recognizer programatically by `self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer:)` in `viewDidLoad()`